# Good tool for system design in Java/Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, oop, uml

Does anyone know of a good tool for laying out class diagrams and the like for eclipse?

Preferably soemthing that will let me draw up the relationships between the classes/interfaces and will then generate stub code for me to fill in.

I've just been handed a 288 page API doc and told to implement it in Java and I want to make sure I have a good design before I start writing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for an UML tool. Check the [relevant Eclipse Plugin Central category](http://www.eclipseplugincentral.com/Web_Links-index-req-viewcatlink-cid-19.html).

Note that UML has been a hype. Today, there are people who can live with its shortcomings and there are people who despise it.

If you just want to collect and sort your ideas, I suggest to try a [wiki](http://moinmo.in/) or a mindmap ([XMind](http://moinmo.in/) or [FreeMind](http://moinmo.in/)).

Comment: I think your links are broken.

Answer (score 2):

I've evaluated several Eclipse based UML tools, and the best by far, in my opinion, was the free edition of Soyatec's eUML2 (http://www.soyatec.com/euml2/).

Having said that, I should qualify that eUML2 was suitable *for me*, in the sense that I was looking for:

1. Primarily clas and sequence diagram creation (which happens to be the only two diagrams type the free version of eUML2 supports).
2. Built-in support for Java libraries (recognizes all classes in the project class path, I was never able to get Rational Software Architect to do this) and features (e.g., inner classes).
3. Basic code generation (specifically, Java Bean getter/setters).
4. Integration with SCMs (more on this below).

If you need more diagrams than what I needed, but are willing to put up with lack of SCM integration, you may want to look into the free version of Omondo EclipseUML (http://www.eclipsedownload.com/ - as far as I can tell, this is a fork of Soyatec's product), which supports 5-6 different diagrams types, IIRC, but will disable itself if it detects that you've turned on SCM integration on your project (which I find very annoying).

Alternative, you can pay for the full versions of either of these. They are really expensive though.

Let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.soyatec.com/euml2/ is for eclipse user.

However personally I am using StarUML, which is not eclipse based (http://staruml.sourceforge.net/en/). I use it because it can start up faster compared to eclipse tools :)

Comment: I agree. I have used StarUML when I needed to come up with diagrams. it is fast, with no noticeable lags in response.

Answer (score 0):

[Design Pattern Toolkit is an Eclipse-enabled tool](http://www.alphaworks.ibm.com/tech/dptk) for generating applications based on customizable, model-driven architecture patterns. This tool automates the use of the best known application development practices. With Design Pattern Toolkit, an expert in the art of developing a particular class of application (such as portlet, Web service, or JDBC bean) can encode the implementation steps that take application requirements and produce a complete, working application.

Comment: http://www.alphaworks.ibm.com/tech/dptk